# after ticking more than one checkbox i get array printed on screen

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have built a checkbox group using forums and everything works on the standalone script that a created but when i add it to my user system afte selecting more than one I get array echoed where the list is supposed to be below is the production script

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbconfig.php';
$chkbox = array('option1', 'option2', 'option3');
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $chkbox = $_POST['chkbox'];

 $chkNew = "";  

 foreach($chkbox as $chkNew1)  
   {  
      $chkNew .= $chkNew1 . ",";  
   }  


 $query = "INSERT INTO demo_table_5 (MultipleValue) VALUES ('$chkNew')";

 mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error());

  }

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PHP Insert/Store multiple selected checkbox values in MySQL database</title>
</head>

<body>

<h2>PHP Insert multiple checkbox values in MySQL database</h2>
 <form method="post" action="">
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]" value="option1"><label>option1</label></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]" value="option2"><label>option2</label></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]" value="option3"><label>option3</label></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="4"><input type="submit" name="submit" Value="submit"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </form>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT MultipleValue FROM demo_table_5";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Interests</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["MultipleValue"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

so when I added it to script I put

```
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]" value="option1"><label>option1</label></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]" value="option2"><label>option2</label></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]" value="option3"><label>option3</label></td>
 </tr>
```

in the register form its self

then I put the following in the php block at the top of the registration page

```
$chkbox = array('option1', 'option2', 'option3');
```

and I added a column to the existing userinfo table in database and named it multipleValue and added the following line to update database

```
MultipleValue       = '".$_POST['chkbox']."',
```

then I added the following bit to the profile page

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT MultipleValue FROM user_info";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table><tr><th>Interests</th></tr>";
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["MultipleValue"]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: So, $row['MultipleValue'] is probably an array itself.  Use var_dump() or print_r() and you can see.  You might have to put another loop inside your while() ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your inputs have `name="chkbox[]"`, this means that `$_POST['chkbox']` is an array containing the values of all the checked boxes. In PHP, when you try to use an array as a string, as in

```
MultipleValue       = '".$_POST['chkbox']."',
```

the array is converted to the string `"Array"`. You need to use `implode` to convert it to a comma-separated list:

```
MultipleValue       = '".implode(',', $_POST['chkbox'])."',
```

However, I recommend you change your table design. Comma-separated values in a table cell are a bad way to represent lists, because it's difficult to search and update them -- indexes can't be used to search for individual values in the list, for instance. You should use a many-to-many table where there's a row for each user+option combination.

Comment: fantastic works a treat ty very much for your help and assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting in the db a concatenated string such as "option1,option2,option3".

Retrieving data by the SQL select statement will return one row containing the concatenation

Comment: would it be best to keep seperate database as in production where it worked fine hun

Comment: also im getting invalid argument error Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /home/jktempla/public_html/registration3.php on line 6

Comment: invalid arguement has now gone forgot to save after edits

Comment: i tried both print_r() and var_dump() and i get print_r()

Warning: print_r() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/jktempla/public_html/profile.php on line 284

Warning: print_r() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/jktempla/public_html/profile.php on line 284
Interests
Array

Comment: Its sorted now hun but ty for your response